# `code dir && exit` causes inifinite opening of vscode

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code

- VS Code Version: v1.55.2
- OS Version: Windows 10

Say we have a file structure like so:

```
current-dir
  └ dir
```

Use `code dir && exit`(bash) will cause infinite opening of vscode, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs in `v1.55.2` but disappears in `v1.56.0`, which needs to be further observed.